# CakePHP's Auth->Login not working in production, but works in test

Tags: cakephp, authentication, autologin

I have a CakePHP website that's been working great.

I just developed a new functionality that at one point auto-logs the user in, and redirects him to a page that's behind the login wall.

This works perfectly well in my dev machine, but in production, the user gets redirected to the login page.

Relevant code: (not much)

```
    $objCustomer = $this->Customer->findById($customerId);
    $this->Auth->login($objCustomer);
    $this->redirect("/customers/signup");
```

Customer is the Model that's used for authentication.

In the server, I see that I AM getting redirected to /customers/signup, and that redirects me to /customers/login

The thing that confuses me the most is that this works perfectly in  my machine.

I dumped the return value of Auth->Login in the server, and it returns 1, so in theory everything is fine and the user should've been logged in.

Some things I can think of that are different between my machine and the server:

- Dev machine is Windows, Server is Linux. This sometimes introduces case-sensitivity issues, but the signup method i'm redirecting to is all lowercase, I don't see where there could be such a problem here.
- Dev machine is IIS, Server is LiteSpeed. Maybe Litespeed is screwing with something? This would be the first time in over a year running this site in production that i'd find something different because of LiteSpeed
- Production site is over SSL, dev is not. I don't see how this could be a problem.

Any ideas are infinitely welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: Is the production site served _entirely_ over SSL? I've been told that sometimes sessions break when switching from/to SSL.

Comment: Interesting point... There is an HTTPS form in Site "A", which posts data to a HTTPS URL in Site "B" (where CakePHP is). The handling of this request, which is over HTTPS, does the auto login, and redirects to another URL, which is also over HTTPS (actually, it doesn't specify protocol for the redirect)

Comment: So yes, everything happens over SSL, **however**, there is never a page rendered and sent to the client from the site in question, so it may be a cookies problem, maybe?
If that's the case, however, the question is why it'd work over HTTP, and not over HTTPs

Comment: That's strange. Have you tried setting cake's security to medium (if it's set to high)? Apparently people had a lot of problems with that.

Comment: Yes, in fact the security level has always been medium, because high logs people out if they try to load more than one page at the same time. So yes, "high" is very unstable :-)
Please, if you have any other ideas, keep them coming, I'm really stuck with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a LOOOONG process of trying different weird things, it turns out it all boils down to this:

```
ini_set('session.referer_check', $this->host);
```

That's part of CakePHP's standard security features... It sets that INI setting.

If the request made to the action that'll call Auth->login is coming from another host (domain/subdomain/whatever), PHP will consider the session invalid, which effectively kills the auto-login attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems too with authentication working fine on my machine in development mode, but not working on the server in production mode. Surprisingly, when I changed the server to development mode it started working correctly. Then I changed back to production, and it was still working. Perhaps it was some cache issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you say "development mode", do you mean this?  Configure::write('debug', 2); -- If that's the case, I just tried it and unfortunately it didn't work. It would still not auto-login even with debug=2.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Is that the only part where the authentication fails, or is authentication not working in general?

Comment: Everything works in the production server, except for this. And this is the only part where I'm "forcing" a login, I normally send the user to the login page and let CakePHP handle it. So yes, this is the only thing failing.